# Why won't this simple If statement check all conditions

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have an if statement that I want to check that all EditTexts are not empty. I know it's something simple but I can't see the problem.

```
     if (name.getText().length()<0 & postalcode.getText().length()<0 & phonenumber.getText().length()<0 & age.getText().length()<0 & staffid.getText().length()<0 & password.getText().length()<0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //alerts user that entry has been saved
    } else {
        database1.insertContact(name.getText().toString(), postalcode.getText().toString(), phonenumber.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString(), staffid.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Entry saved :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //alerts user that entry has been saved

        //Intent to go back home
        Intent showContent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), login.class);
        startActivity(showContent);
    }
```

Comment: your if statement will always evaluate to false because length can't be less than 0. Try using == instead.

Comment: First of all, your &'s in your if check should be the binary &&, not the unary &. No reason to check the proceeding fields if the prior ones are false.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and it stayed the same

Comment: Try my answer! you need to use OR and not AND as even one edit text being empty is not correct

Comment: Msk thanks for you help you solved it :)

Comment: A green tick for the question will be welcome;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even one being empty is not correct right. So using and operator is not right

```
  if (name.getText().length()==0 || postalcode.getText().length()==0 || phonenumber.getText().length()==0 || age.getText().length()==0 || staffid.getText().length()==0 || password.getText().length()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //alerts user that entry has been saved
```

Using and will not work as then it will only say that edittext is empty if all edittexts are empty! You need to use or in the way stated above

Answer (score 2):

should you be using = 0 instead of < 0? i am not an familiar with android language but I think length of a blank text would normally be 0 instead of -1.